# Query in Microsoft SQL Server using Datetime Convert

Tags: php, sql-server

I want to know how can I query data using datetime convert:

Example if in ORACLE using :

```
WHERE TO_CHAR(FQA_END_DATE,'YYYY-MM-DD') = '2014-03-25'
```

How about in SQL Server ?

```
WHERE ...
```

Please help to advice.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In sql server you can do something like

```
WHERE CAST(Date_Column AS DATE) = '20140325'   --<--  'YYYYMMDD'  ANSI Standard
```

or

```
WHERE CAST(Date_Column AS DATE) = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
```

Comment: I got error like this : Lookup Error - SQL Server Database Error: Type DATE is not a defined system type.

Comment: What version of sql server you are on ?

Answer (score 0):

If FQA_END_DATE is a **datetime** datatype; you do not need to make a conversion to characters to compare it to a character string. You just need to provide the character string in an unambigious format, which for example would be the ISO format yyyyMMdd;

so if FQA_END_DATE is a datetime this would work:

```
WHERE FQA_END_DATE = '20140325'
```

If however,t hen FQA_END_DATE contains a *time* portion as well as date, and you're only interested in comparing on date part (and you do not have DATE data type), a good number of methods exists, but a trick is to run it past float;

```
WHERE CAST(FLOOR(CAST(FQA_END_DATE AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME) = '20140325'
```

That converts/removes the time portion from your datetime variable.
The same can also be achieved by using DATEPART or DATEDIFF functions.

Ultimately - you can use the CONVERT to convert both sides of the WHERE into the same date format;

```
WHERE CONVERT(DATETIME, FQA_END_DATE, 112) = CONVERT(DATETIME, '20140325', 112)
```

Many many approaches exists to this issue, hopefully this will give some inspiration.

The best advice I can give you is if handling dates as string, to use the ISO format of yyyyMMdd (20140325) because SQL Server can automatically convert that.